# How do I test Repository pattern in .NET Core

Tags: c#, unit-testing, nunit, moq, repository-pattern

I am trying to setup tests using Moq + Nunit.

I am using the Repository pattern

```
public interface IRepository<T> where T : class
{
    Task<List<T>> FindByConditionAsync(Expression<Func<T, bool>> expression);
    Task<List<T>> GetAllAsync();
    //...
}

public class Repository<TEntity, TContext> : IRepository<TEntity> 
{
    //...Omitted other code from this snippet

    public async Task<List<TEntity>> FindByConditionAsync(Expression<Func<TEntity, bool>> expression)
    {
        return await _context.Set<TEntity>().Where(expression).ToListAsync();
    }
}

public interface IUserRepository : IRepository<User>
{

}

public class UserRepository : Repository<User, MyDatabase>, IUserRepository
{
    public UserRepository(MyDatabase context) : base(context)
    {
    }
}
```

My test file

```
public class UserProviderTests
{
    private IMapper _mapper;
    private UserProvider _userProvider;
    private Mock<MyDatabase> _mockContext;
    private UserRepository _userRepository;
    
    [SetUp]
    public void Setup()
    {
        var user1Guid = Guid.NewGuid();
        var user2Guid = Guid.NewGuid();
        var data = new List<User>
        {
            new User
            {
                Id = user1Guid,
                FirstName = "Optimus", 
                LastName = "Prime"
            },
            new User
            {
                Id = user2Guid,
                FirstName = "John",
                LastName = "Doe",
            }
        }.AsQueryable();

        var mockSet = new Mock<DbSet<User>>();
        mockSet.As<IQueryable<User>>().Setup(m => m.Provider).Returns(data.Provider);
        mockSet.As<IQueryable<User>>().Setup(m => m.Expression).Returns(data.Expression);
        mockSet.As<IQueryable<User>>().Setup(m => m.ElementType).Returns(data.ElementType);
        mockSet.As<IQueryable<User>>().Setup(m => m.GetEnumerator()).Returns(data.GetEnumerator());

        var options = new DbContextOptionsBuilder<MyDatabase>()
            .UseSqlServer("fakestring")
            .Options;

        _mockContext = new Mock<MyDatabase>(options);

        _mockContext.Setup(c => c.Users).Returns(mockSet.Object);
        _userRepository = new UserRepository(_mockContext.Object);

        var config = new MapperConfiguration(cfg => {
            cfg.AddProfile<MappingProfile>();
        });
        _mapper = new Mapper(config);
        
        _userProvider = new UserProvider(_mapper, _userRepository);
    }

    [Test]
    public async Task GetUsers_ReturnsSingleUser()
    {
        var users = await _userProvider.FindUser("xxx");
        Assert.AreEqual("xxx", users.FirstOrDefault()?.FirstName);
    }
}
```

UserProvider is a service I am using that uses UserRepository to perform CRUD operations.
But When I try to run this test, I get error saying -

> System.ArgumentNullException : Value cannot be null. (Parameter 'source')
> Stack Trace:
> Queryable.Where[TSource](IQueryable'1 source, Expression'1 predicate)
> Repository'2.FindByConditionAsync(Expression'1 expression) line 48

Sorry for the long question, but am I missing something here? I don't understand why TSource(USer object) is null.

Comment: IQueryables are pretty difficult to mock, so if you don’t want to reimplement a lot of logic there, either abstract that away so you don’t have to test it, or consider using an in-memory database with EF Core instead of attempting to mock your DbSets.

Comment: There are a couple of 3rd libraries as well who already solved this problem. Just to name a few: [Moq.EntityFrameworkCore](https://github.com/MichalJankowskii/Moq.EntityFrameworkCore), [EntityFrameworkCore3Mock](https://github.com/cup-of-tea-dot-be/entity-framework-core3-mock), [EntityFrameworkCore.Testing](https://github.com/rgvlee/EntityFrameworkCore.Testing), etc.

Answer (score -1):

In my opinion, you should write a test for services in your project. In fact, you shouldn't write any business in the RepositoryLayer because there isn't any business rule in the Repository. If you need to help more please contact me.
dpournabi@gmail.com